# Order of operator precedence when using ":" (the colon)

Tags: r, operator-precedence, r-faq

I am trying to extract values from a vector using numeric vectors expressed in two seemingly equivalent ways:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
x[2:3]
# [1] 2 3
x[1+1:3]
# [1]  2  3 NA
```

I am confused why the expression `x[2:3]` produces a result different from `x[1+1:3]` -- the second includes an `NA` value at the end. What am I missing?

Comment: 1+1 = 2 (the second element), 1+2=3 (the third element) and 1+3=4 (the fourth element) and your vector is only three elements long.  There is no fourth element so you get NA.  Try (1+1):3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the operator `:` has precedence over `+` so `1+1:3` is really `1+(1:3)` (i. e. `2:4`) and not `2:3`. Thus, to change the order of execution as defined operator precedence, use parentheses `()`

You can see the order of precedence of operators in the help file `?Syntax`. Here is the relevant part:

> The following unary and binary operators are defined. They are listed in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.
>      `::` `:::`  access variables in a namespace
>      `$` `@`     component / slot extraction
>      `[` `[[`    indexing
>      `^`         exponentiation (right to left)
>      `-` `+`     unary minus and plus
>      `:`         sequence operator
>      `%any%`     special operators (including `%%` and `%/%`)
>      `*` `/`     multiply, divide
>      `+` `-`     (binary) add, subtract