# Applying split function to overlapping rows of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, split, apply

Suppose I have a matrix which looks like this:

```
[1] a b c 
[2] d e f
[3] g h i
[4] j k l
[5] m n o
[6] p q r
```

Now I want to split this matrix into smaller ones with each 3 rows, starting from the first row, then the second, ..., so it looks like this in the end:

```
[1] a b c
[2] d e f
[3] g h i

[1] d e f
[2] g h i
[3] j k l

[1] g h i
[2] j k l
[3] m n o
...
```

I tried the following code, which didn't do it for me:

```
lapply(split(1:nrow(matrix),(1:nrow(matrix)-1) %/%3+1),
              function(i) matrix[i,])
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: [Order of operator precedence when using “:” (the colon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095238/order-of-operator-precedence-when-using-the-colon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` method showed in the OP's post will split into blocks of 3 rows and that will not be mutually exclusive.  Whereas if we want to split in a way that each `list` element starts with each of the rows of the `matrix` and the next two rows,  we can loop through the sequence of rows, get the sequence from that index to the next two and subset the `matrix`

```
lapply(head(seq_len(nrow(matrix)), -2), function(i) matrix[i:(i+2),])
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
#[2,] "d"  "e"  "f" 
#[3,] "g"  "h"  "i" 

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "d"  "e"  "f" 
#[2,] "g"  "h"  "i" 
#[3,] "h"  "k"  "l" 

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "g"  "h"  "i" 
#[2,] "h"  "k"  "l" 
#[3,] "m"  "n"  "o" 

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "h"  "k"  "l" 
[2,] "m"  "n"  "o" 
[3,] "p"  "q"  "r"
```

Or as @lmo suggested, another version of the above would be

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(matrix) -2L) - 1L, function(x) matrix[x + 1:3,])
```

---

or another option is to create the splitting group with `rollapply` (from `zoo`) and then do the `split`

```
library(zoo)
grp <- rollapply(seq_len(nrow(matrix)), 3, FUN = I)
lapply(split(grp, row(grp)), function(i) matrix[i, ])
```

NOTE: `matrix` is a function name.  It is better not to name objects with function names or other reserved words

#### data

```
matrix <- structure(c("a", "d", "g", "h", "m", "p", "b", "e", "h", "k", 
      "n", "q", "c", "f", "i", "l", "o", "r"), .Dim = c(6L, 3L))
```

Comment: Mostly taste, but this is a bit clearer to me: `lapply(seq_len(nrow(myMat) -2L) - 1L, function(x) myMat[x + 1:3,])`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!